# Write Geopy location to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, geopy

I'm trying to write the output of this `geopy` object to a `csv` file, but it puts each letter in a different column and prints the latitude and longitude on a different line. How can I fix that?

I would like to be able to run this function at different times and print the new address to the next line. Saving the data not overwriting it. Can this be done with write `csv` in python?

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import csv

def loc_find(file):
'''
This function take in a user given location and gives back the address with 
city, zip code, state, county and country.
It also provides latitude and longitude.
'''
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    loc_input = raw_input("Add the location you would like data back for: ")
    location = geolocator.geocode(loc_input)
    print(location.address)
    print((location.latitude, location.longitude))

    with open(r"", 'w') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp)
        data = location
        a.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are passing a single [`Location`](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/index.html?highlight=location#geopy.location.Location) object as [`rows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) (a list of row objects), you should pass it as a single row.

Replace:

```
a.writerows(location)
```

With:

```
a.writerow(location)
```

Comment: That works better but if I run this with a place "RedLands" I get Redlands, San Bernardino County, California, United States of America (34.0715385, -117.120993253739) I would like each in its own column. Would like one row with 6 columns if opened in excel